# Install a gem to use as a tool in building a python project on Travis

Tags: ruby, travis-ci

TL;DR how can I install a Ruby gem on Travis for a non-ruby (mostly Python) project, such that I can use the executable that gem provides as part of the build system.

I'm trying to install a Ruby gem for use in building some extra stuff in my [python project](https://github.com/pyFFTW/pyFFTW), post-testing and before deployment. Specifically, I want to use [github-changelog-generator](https://github.com/skywinder/github-changelog-generator) to auto generate the changelog for me.

It seems I can't install to root, because the new containerised builds on Travis don't allow `sudo`.

I've tried installing using `gem install --user-install github_changelog_generator`. Initially, just that gave a `command not found` error when running `github_changelog_generator`.

Trying `export PATH="$(ruby -rubygems -e 'puts Gem.user_dir')/bin:$PATH"` prior to running `github_changelog_generator` results in the following:

```
/home/travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:315:in `to_specs': Could not find 'github_changelog_generator' (>= 0) among 14 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551:/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global', execute `gem env` for more information
    from /home/travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:324:in `to_spec'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:64:in `gem'
    from /home/travis/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/bin/github_changelog_generator:22:in `<main>'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

which would suggest to me it has sort of found it but doesn't quite understand something.

I've no doubt this is obvious to someone with more Ruby experience than I have.

The current travis yaml snippet is as follows:

```
after_success:
  - gem install --user-install github_changelog_generator
  - export PATH="$(ruby -rubygems -e 'puts Gem.user_dir')/bin:$PATH"    
  - github_changelog_generator -u pyFFTW -p pyFFTW
```

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE:**

I didn't realize RVM wasn't initialized on Python projects, so the fix is to let RVM setup the environment, e.g. by installing a version of Ruby (instead of default 1.9.3 in the container):

```
before_install:
  - rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles
  - rvm install 2.3.1
```

or, if you want the default version of RVM Ruby:

```
before_install:
  - rvm default
```

or, if you want to only install RVM if the build is successful (e.g. you expect Travis failures more often than not):

```
after_success:
  - rvm default
```

RVM will setup `GEM_HOME` and `GEM_PATH` for you, so that commands like `gem` and `bundler` will use the correct Ruby and paths.

**(Previous answer follows - still useful for debugging)**

If you're installing gems, PATH is not the only important variable to locate and load a gem. You also need to properly set GEM_HOME and GEM_PATH.

If in doubt, before the `gem install` run `gem env`, which will show you the whole current gem environment (where gems are installed, what the PATH is, etc.). You can also run `gem list` to verify that the gem is properly installed and available. `gem contents github_changelog_generator` will show you exactly where the files were installed.

If you paste the output, it will become obvious what needs to change.

Travis also uses bundler for loading gems, so if you have a `Gemfile` and that gem isn't in the `Gemfile`, it might be ignored in some cases.

Again, out from `gem env` should give clues on what the Ruby environment looks like on a python project/container.

BTW, what does the rest of the .travis.yml file look like? Do you have a `language` set? Do you have `sudo: false` set?

Comment: Yes, `language: python` and `sudo: false` are set. I'll take a look at the other outputs. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. The solution was to enable the relevant `rvm`, which was as easy as doing `rvm default`, then removing the `--user-install` argument. So: `rvm default` followed by `gem install github_changelog_generator`. It would be great if you could add that to you answer for completeness, and I'll mark it correct.